# How to match exact character from my SQL table column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to write a query that will return a specific character from the table column.

For instance, let's say I have a category column that has the values:

```
2:3:1:11:4
```

and I want to match a specific number in that string; for example, trying to match `1`.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events` 
WHERE `category` LIKE '_1' 
AND SortDate LIKE '%2017-02%' 
AND status=1
```

Comment: https://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/removing-part-of-string-before-and-after-specific-character-using-transact-sql-string-functions/

Comment: You should review your database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events` 
WHERE `category` regexp '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
AND SortDate LIKE '%2017-02%' 
AND status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard characters around the value you are trying to match, if you don't care where it occurs in the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events` 
WHERE (`category` LIKE '1:%' OR `category` LIKE '%:1:%' OR `category` LIKE '%:1')
AND SortDate LIKE '%2017-02%' 
AND status=1
```

Comment: Won't work -- will catch `11` by mistake in `2:3:11:4`

Answer (score 0):

If you used commas instead of colons, you could use `FIND_IN_SET`.

But the 'right' way to do it is to have an mapping table between `events` and `categories`.  Here are [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on the optimal many:many table design.

`LIKE '%2017-02%'` does not need the leading `%`.